# CSS & jQuery (Q1): Best light-weight method to switch from slide to slide on click

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I create small animated graphics using CSS and jQuery. There are a series of animations which switch from slide to slide when you click on a button.

I currently use this method:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#z-tab1").click(function() {
$(".zSlide1").removeClass("zhide");
$(".zSlide2").removeClass("zshow");
$(".zSlide3").removeClass("zshow");

//hide previous slides
$(".zSlide1").addClass("zshow");
$(".zSlide2").addClass("zhide");
$(".zSlide3").addClass("zhide");

</script>
<style>
.zhide{ display:none; }
.zshow{ display:block;}

/*slide 1 */
.zSlide1 {
width:100%;
height:100%;
max-width:600px;
min-height:500px;
min-width:320px;}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: `ibnewzSlide1` classes or ids?

Comment: Try $(".ibnewzSlide1, .ibnewzSlide2, etc ").toggleClass("ibzshow");

Comment: zSlide is a class, thank you for asking.

Comment: What is `"#z-tab1"`, is there a `"#z-tab2"` also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:
    // set an active slide to display when page loads
    $('.elem1').addClass('activeSlide');

```
// count your elements(which class name starts with "elem") and push them into an array
var 
elems = 0,
i = 1;

$('[class^="elem"]').each(function(){
    elems +=1;
});

// display one element at a time, by modifying the z-index value
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    i+=1;
    if(i > elems ){ i = 1; };
    $('[class^="elem' + i + '"]').addClass('activeSlide').siblings().removeClass('activeSlide');
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/WrQ4L/1/

Keep in mind that this method requires to have class names numbered ascending(the initial value of "i" is equal to the first class number -> elem1)

Answer (score 1):

Just link classes and toggle their display

```
$("#z-tab1").click(function() {

    $(".zSlide1, .zSlide2, .zSlide3").toggle();

});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the super quick response I will give this a try :D - cheers!

Comment: @heymega I think you should fix your `toggle()` selector'

Comment: @MarkS Could you not have?

Comment: @heymega could I not have? Yes I could have? :P